# Is it possible to use apply function or vectorization on this code logic?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization, apply

I am trying to calculate closing balance

Input dataframe:

```
    open   inOut    close
0   3      100      0
1   0      300      0
2   0      200      0
3   0      230      0
4   0      150      0
```

Output DataFrame

```
    open    inOut   close
0   3       100     103
1   103     300     403
2   403     200     603
3   603     230     833
4   833     150     983
```

I am able to achieve this using crude **for-loop** and to optimize it i have used **iterrow()**

**For-Loop**

```
%%timeit
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    if i>0:
        df.iloc[i]['open'] = df.iloc[i-1]['close']
        df.iloc[i]['close'] = df.iloc[i]['open']+df.iloc[i]['inOut']
    else:
        df.iloc[i]['close'] = df.iloc[i]['open']+df.iloc[i]['inOut'] 

1.64 ms ± 51.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**iterrows**

```
%%timeit
for index,row in dfOg.iterrows():
    if index>0:
        row['open'] = dfOg.iloc[index-1]['close']
        row['close'] = row['open']+row['inOut']
    else:
        row['close'] = row['open']+row['inOut']

627 µs ± 28.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

> performance optimized from 1.64ms -> 627µs

As per this [blog](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6), I am struggling to figure out how to write the above logic using apply() and vectorization.
for vectorization, I tried shifting the columns but not able to achieve the desired output.

Comment: *I'm sorry, I made a silly mistake in the closing balance logic*

Comment: `.apply` is not vectorization

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes i agree, but as per the blog i mentioned, apply is faster than itterrows()

Comment: You should use `itertuples` and apply won't really be faster than that. Note, your `iterrows` version doesn't work, it doesn't modify the original data-frame

Comment: thanks, @juanpa.arrivillaga ill check the performance of itertuples as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: I changed things around to match the edits OP made to the question**

You can do what you want in a vectorized way without any loops like this:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'open': [3] + [0]*4, 'inOut': [100, 300, 200, 230, 150], 'close': [0]*5}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df['close'].values[:] = df['open'].values[0] + df['inOut'].values.cumsum()
df['open'].values[1:] = df['close'].values[:-1]
```

Timing with `%%timeit`:

```
529 µs ± 5.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Output:

```
   close  inOut  open
0    103    100     3
1    403    300   103
2    603    200   403
3    833    230   603
4    983    150   833
```

So vectorizing your code this way is indeed somewhat faster. In fact, it's probably about as fast as possible. You can see this by timing just the dataframe creation code:

```
%%timeit
d = {'open': [3] + [0]*4, 'inOut': [100, 300, 200, 230, 150], 'close': [0]*5}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Result:

```
367 µs ± 5.67 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Subtracting out the time it takes to create the dataframe, the vectorized version of filling in your dataframe only takes about ~160 µs.

Comment: kindly revisit the question.
btw i like this simple approach, but i doubt will this work to calc closing balance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where`

```
%%timeit
df['open'] = np.where(df.index==0, df['open'], df['inOut'].shift())
df['close'] = df['open'] + df['inOut']
# 1.07 ms ± 16.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Output:

```
    open    inOut   close
0   3.0     100     103.0
1   100.0   300     300.0
2   300.0   200     200.0
3   200.0   230     230.0
4   230.0   150     150.0
```

Comment: That's pretty slick, but it's slow. I guess from the array construction that `np.where` does?

Comment: @tel yeah it's bit slower than your answer as there's condition check in `np.where`